# cluster r script isn't reading in RData datasets properly

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

I'm trying to run this job on our cluster, and I keep getting this "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" error. It basically runs this function "do_1()" on a bunch of nodes. The closure object I'm subsetting is called "data" so I take this to mean that the RData files are not reading in on each node (it's probably not best practices to call each of these individual datasets "data" so that's my bad).

I stripped the script down to something as bare bones as possible, and it's displayed below. It still produces the same error when I submit the job. I figure there's something I don't know about reading in separate data sets on each node...some argument I didn't specify in the call to load() maybe. Maybe the "data" dataset isn't in the right namespace or something...I'm not sure. Any ideas will be kindly appreciated.

```
library(parallel)
library(Rmpi)

np <- mpi.universe.size()
cl <- makeCluster(np, type = "MPI")

allFiles <- list.files("/bigtmp/trb5me/rdata_files/")
allFiles <- sapply(allFiles, function(string) paste("/bigtmp/trb5me/rdata_files/", string, sep = ""))

run_one_day <- function(daynum){

  # do we want to subset days to not the first hour?
  train <- data[[daynum]] * 10000
  train
}
clusterExport(cl = cl, "run_one_day")

do_1 <- function(path_to_file){

  if(!require(xts)){
    install.packages("xts")
    library(xts)
  }

  # load data
  load(file=path_to_file)

  # extract the symbol name so we cna save the results later
  symbolName <- strsplit(path_to_file, "/")[[1]][5]
  symbolName <- strsplit(symbolName, ".", fixed = T)[[1]][1]

  # get the results
  # there is also a function called data...so in this case it's length will be 1
  mySequence <- 1:(length(data)-1)
  myResults <- lapply(mySequence, run_one_day)   #this is where the problem is! 

  # save the results
  path_dest <- paste("/bigtmp/trb5me/mod1_results/", symbolName, ".RData", sep = "")
  save(myResults, file = path_dest)

  # remove everything from memory
  rm(list=ls())

}

parLapply(cl, allFiles, do_1)

# turn off all the cluster stuff
stopCluster(cl)
mpi.exit()
```

Comment: Where does the error come from within that function? try including options(error = traceback)

Comment: Wait, I see; nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` variable is only available on the master, not on the slaves.
Since there also happens to be a function called `data`, that is what they try to use, 
and subsetting it with `[[` gives the error message you get.

Try exporting the `data` variable to the other nodes before the computation.

```
clusterExport(cl, "data")
```

Comment: It's only available on the master even though 'load()' is being called on each node? This implies that different RData files can't be loaded on separate nodes. Is that true?

Comment: @Taylor load puts the data inside the environment of `do_1`, which `run_one_day` doesn't have access to. You're be better off passing it as an argument to `run_one_day`, and even better using `readRDS`/`saveRDS`.

Comment: It looks to me that the "data" variable is only available on the workers since it is loaded by the "do_1" function which is only executed on the workers via parLapply. clusterExport doesn't make sense in that context.

Comment: @SteveWeston: You are right: since there was no `data <-` anywhere, I had assumed that the variable
was defined somewhere before. 
I also prefer `saveRDS` and `readRDS`: 
`save` and `load` hide the name of the variables being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

It's a scoping problem: "data" is loaded in the local environment of "do_1" which isn't in the scope of the "run_one_day" function. R uses lexical scoping, so what matters is where "run_one_day" is defined, not where it is called.

One solution is to use the load "envir" argument to load "data" into the global environment:

```
load(file=path_to_file, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Another solution is to define "run_one_day" inside the "do_1" function.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly wrong, but it looks like the error is actually in `train <- data[[daynum]]`. It's trying to subset the *function*, or "closure", data and, of course, bugging out. Try naming your dataset something other than 'data' and see what happens.